# How to paginate Stripe Invoice in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

How do you paginate stripe invoices? Let’s say for example we have a table of 10 invoices on the front end.

```
const invoices = await stripe.invoices.list({
  limit: 10
});
```

I’m trying to determine the front end logic for displaying the previous and Next buttons. How do you determine when the previous button is displayed? Any examples would be appreciated even if pseudo code.

Answer (score 0):

Stripe has [detailed pagination documentation in their API reference](https://stripe.com/docs/api/pagination) that should provide the information you need.

Specifically, it sounds like you want to use the `starting_after` property combined with a `limit`.